# Objective C float to NSString

Tags: json, objective-c

In my application I am having code like this

```
financialCost = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[valueFromBank objectForKey:@"Cost"]];
 
[valueFromBank objectForKey:@"Cost"] // This value comes from JSON through Websocket event.
```

Everything working fine. The problem I am facing is

When I get json value as 5 it is working fine
When I get json value as 6.1 it is working fine

But strangely when I get the json value as 8.3 then it shows as 8.3100001200
For the value 9.1 it is shows 9.1000002200

I want to show 8.3 and 9.1 accurately.

Is there any solution for this problem.

Comment: See this https://blog.skagedal.tech/2017/12/30/decimal-decoding.html - as mentioned there this is a conversion problem and the solution may be to treat the json as string if possible.

Comment: Maybe show how you convert the json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the decoding trouble that even can happen with calculation of simple mathematical expressions.
In deserialized JSON as dictionary decimals arrive as Objects and can be read as NSNumber.

```
// just an given example JSON as NSDictionary
NSDictionary *valueFromBank = @{@"Cost":@(8.3100001200), @"second":@9.1000002200, @"third":@"8.3100001200"};
```

```
NSNumber *numberCost = [valueFromBank objectForKey:@"Cost"];
NSLog(@"as NSNumber %@",numberCost);
```

NSNumber is **8.31000012** here as given in example dict.
The magic of NSNumber is, the object can be a written decimal NSString also. So that

```
NSNumber *numberCostV2 = [valueFromBank objectForKey:@"third"];
```

is still understood as NSNumber **8.31000012**

```
float floatCost = [numberCostV2 floatValue];
NSLog(@"as float %f",floatCost);
```

float is **8.310000** here.

```
NSString *financialCost = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",floatCost];
NSLog(@"as NSString withFormat %@", financialCost);
```

NSString in format is **8.31**

What to learn from it?
Seems simple, but the golden rule is to convert in the last step, if possible or with exact accuracy as needed. And sometime NSString is helping you out and/or does it make worse.

```
NSDecimalNumber *decimal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:8.124];
NSLog(@"as double %f and as NSString %@", [decimal doubleValue], [decimal stringValue]);
```

as **double 8.124000** and as **NSString 8.124000000000002048**

Comment: And yes, pretty sure thats the reason why we have so much wonky midi clocks. :D